# How to get the text from the latest chat bubble when automating chatbot using Selenium

Tags: java, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver

When automating chatbot using Selenium, I want to print the latest chat bubble's text. But instead, the code is printing the text from the very first chat bubble of the chat. How can I get the latest chat bubble's text if all chat bubbles have the same html code?

[image]

The selenium code I use to get the text from the chat bubble.

```
String kk = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@class='Linkify']//span")).getText();
```

The html code of the chat bubble whose text I want to get. All chat bubble have the same code, with the difference being the text in between the span tags

```
<div class="bubble-content">
  <span class="message-content">
    <div style="white-space: pre-wrap;">
      <span class="Linkify">
        <span>You can bookmark this tab, I am always here. I will be in touch once I get any updates.
        </span>
      </span>
    </div>
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: I cannot test this right now, but I think you can do `"//*[@class='Linkify'][last()]//span"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`findElement` will return the first matching element in the DOM, the first chat bubble. Toy can use `findElements` to locate all of them and get the text of the last one in the list

```
List<WebElement> allChats = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@class='Linkify']//span"))
String kk = allChats.get(allChats.size() - 1).getText();
```